# php autoloading does not work on version 5.2.17

Tags: php, autoload

on my locale machine evrything works but when i uploaded to godaddy server the autoload function does not work.
godaddys php version is: 5.2.17.
i get this error:
Fatal error: __autoload() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/content/b/r/e/me/html/classes/Shtigliz_Database.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/b/r/e/me/html/config/bootstrap.php on line 52

the paths are correct af far as i checked. godaddy support say its my code, but it does work on my local machine.

this is my code:

```
function __autoload($class){


if(file_exists(APP_DIR . "/models/$class.php")){

    require APP_DIR . "/models/$class.php";
    }else{

        require APP_DIR . "/classes/$class.php";

    }
```

}

and the APP_DIR constant is set like so:

```
define('APP_DIR', realpath('.'));
```

again, as far as my checks the paths are correct.

are there issues with autoloading in php version 5.2.17?

best regards

Comment: autoloading does work in 5.2. However, you should be warned that 5.2 has been unsupported for two years, and has known security flaws that have not and will not be patched.

Comment: that is the php version that godaddy gives me:)

Comment: really?? I'm surprised a host the size of godaddy would allow that kind of risk on their networks. Any sane/competent network operator would have upgraded some time ago. Also, I note this page: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7804/updating-to-php-53  (I'm not a godaddy customer, so I don't know the situation for sure, but that page seems to imply that they upgraded to 5.3 last year. In any case, it's worth contacting support to confirm).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with Autoload. Your error message indicates that it PHP is having trouble finding the file that you are trying to include. The file is either not there, or it has a permissions problem and isn't accessible by the PHP script.

Comment: well, first thanks for answering. the files are there and the paths are good and i made a 777 permissions. i have tried all these and the same messages.

Comment: Remember that Linux/Unix servers' filesystems distinguish between lowercase and capital letters. Are your file names *exactly* the same?

Comment: yes,i am desperate.again,all works on my locale machine. can i upload here my local phpinfo and godaddys? maybe i am missing something there?

Comment: @Ron is your local machine a Windows machine? On Windows it would accept, say, `shtigliz_database.php` but on the remote machine it has to match `Shtigliz_Database.php` exactly. You are 10000% sure that `/home/content/b/r/e/me/html/classes/Shtigliz_Database.php` exists? Super duper triple sure? That is almost impossible if the name is right, and the permissions are correct.... I can think of no reason why this wouldn't work. My guess is still a typo or something.

Comment: now i see that on the error message it say: Database while the filename is: databse. should i change the file name?

Comment: i have changed the d to D, and now i get a blanck page

Comment: @Ron that's likely to be a new problem, maybe in Shtigliz_Database.php. [Activate error reporting](http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_enable_error_reporting_in_a_php_script/) to see what's happening

Comment: so maybe i should change all my files names and after it works there upload again? or maybe there is a way to tell the server to take the loawer letters?

Comment: The blank screen is unlikely to have to do with the autoloading problem. It must be something else, but it's impossible to tell what exactly. Maybe a syntax problem in the PHP file you're importing. (But yeah, you'll need to make sure all file names match exactly on the remote server - but renaming should be enough) Edit - nope, there isn't a good way to force case insensitivity on server side. I'd rename the files.

Comment: sorry, i had to attend somewhere else. i will do it first on my local machine. does folder names must start with capital too? and does it apply to all files names or just those with underscores?

Comment: @Ron the file names simply have to match exactly the name you are trying to open. ie. if you're autoloading `TestClass`, you can't look for the `testclass` file.

Comment: @Ron where does it ask for Shtigliz_database?

Comment: hi,first sorry i did not noticed your last comment. after changing first letters to capital ones on my local machine and all works, i uploaded to the remote server and now it asked for the lower letter one. am i crazy? this is the error i get:Fatal error: __autoload() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/content/b/r/e/me/html/classes/Shtigliz_session.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/b/r/e/me/html/config/bootstrap.php on line 31. the file is now called:Shtigliz_Session.php. please help again

Comment: if i change the file name to whqat it asks i get this:session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/b/r/e/me/html/bd4fbf5fde58e7f20593bb6a6241a63a/sess_435dudqef896rsoa8rje3i0q24, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13). but why permission denied?if i should change permissions to what exactly?

Comment: @Ron that sounds like a configuration problem on your server, you should talk to the server admin

Comment: first sorry i was not available for such a long time. i have made a php.ini file and wrote session.save_path but no change.i still think something is wrong with godaddy

Comment: this is crazy,i changed some permissions and now i get the same failed require again.but once with a capital letter and once with small letters.this is f*** up